# Message CRC check in protocol working on top of USB HID

Tags: embedded, usb, hid

Do i need to implement message CRC protection in protocol working on top of USB HID custom device? 
It seems to be USB packets already have CRC and i don't get corrupted reports(packets).  So if my protocol message fits in 64 bytes i can omit CRC, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct.  USB transfers have a 16-bit CRC on each packet and robust error handling so you shouldn't worry about implementing your own.